# How to create a dataview In Sharepoint with data from a join query?

Tags: sharepoint, dataview

I have 3 Lists in Sharepoint.

I want to create a dataview that is a join of 3 tables.

Table1 is joined with Table2 on FieldA
Table 2 is joined to Table3 on FieldB

Table1 has duplicate values in FieldA so I need to only return one value to join with Table2.

In Access my query looks like this:
SELECT DISTINCT WRK_InputWorkOrders.WorkOrder, Production1.[Part Number], Production1.[Work Order], Production1.Location, StationItems.Station, Production1.Description, Production1.Revision, WRK_InputWorkOrders.Status
FROM StationItems INNER JOIN (WRK_InputWorkOrders INNER JOIN Production1 ON WRK_InputWorkOrders.WorkOrder = Production1.[Work Order]) ON StationItems.Item = Production1.[Part Number]
WHERE (((WRK_InputWorkOrders.Status)<>"closed"));

Is there a way to write sql-like queries for dataviews?

I have Sharepoint Designer 2007 and Access.

The goal is to get a report that a user can view in Internet Explorer.
I have tried using [this](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointdesigner/HA100991441033.aspx) method. But it returns duplicate records
I found [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/timpash/archive/2005/11/23/XPATH-Filtering-Distinct-Values.aspx) suggestion. It suggests using an XPath Filter
not(@yourvalue = preceding-sibling::dfs:YourRepeatingRowName/@yourvalue)

But wasn't able to get it to work. I don't know what to enter as YourRepeatingRowName

I found [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/sharepointdesigner/archive/2007/04/24/spdatasource-and-rollups-with-the-data-view.aspx) link. Does anyone know if it can be used to perform such a join?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is more of an ADO.NET question. Unfortunately ADO.NET doesn't have an easy way to do this, which is why companies like bamboo Solutions builds theirCross List Web Part:
http://store.bamboosolutions.com/pc-42-1-cross-list-web-part.aspx

Otherwise I would attempt to use LINQ to query the tables. You might have more luck doing that.

Here is an example of a JOIN query provided by MS (I only changed the first two DataTable lines to represent filling a DataTable with an SPListItemCollection object)

```
DataTable orders = spListCol1.ToDataTable();
DataTable details = spListCol2.ToDataTable();

var query =
    from order in orders.AsEnumerable()
    join detail in details.AsEnumerable()
    on order.Field<int>("SalesOrderID") equals
        detail.Field<int>("SalesOrderID")
    where order.Field<bool>("OnlineOrderFlag") == true
    && order.Field<DateTime>("OrderDate").Month == 8
    select new
    {
        SalesOrderID =
            order.Field<int>("SalesOrderID"),
        SalesOrderDetailID =
            detail.Field<int>("SalesOrderDetailID"),
        OrderDate =
            order.Field<DateTime>("OrderDate"),
        ProductID =
            detail.Field<int>("ProductID")
    };

DataTable orderTable = query.CopyToDataTable();
```

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has a video demo and a writeup that may be just what you want:

Display data from multiple sources in a single Data View
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointdesigner/HA103511401033.aspx

*With Microsoft Office SharePoint Designer 2007, you can link two or more data sources that contain related data and then create a single Data View that displays data from those linked data sources.*

Comment: This works except one gets duplicate records. The info doesn't show how to return DISTINCT records.

Comment: This link is dead (unsurprising after 8 years).

Answer (score 0):

you want to show the query result in SharePoint Designer? I believe, SPD has merged data sources. Look into that.

Comment: I have tried using the merged datasources using info from http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointdesigner/HA100991441033.aspx
This method does a join which yields a very large dataset.
Performance is very slow as well. one table has 20,000 rows.

Comment: That's true... if you move the data to a SQL database, you can have views to achieve this.. i hope i made sense :)

Answer (score 0):

I found this third part add on

> Enesys RS Data Extension lets you query (retrieve, join, merge,...) data from any SharePoint list and use the result for building "Reporting Services" reports as you would do with any other data sources. http://www.enesyssoftware.com/

I can't use it because I am currently running the basic Sharepoint version that uses the internal database.

Answer (score 0):

I've done something like this, but I wasn't able to use a dataview. I ended up writing a custom web part to do it. The approach was:

1. Use an `SPQuery` object to get an `SPListItemCollection` for each list. Use the CAML query to restrict the items returned.
2. Use the `SPListItemCollection` object's `GetDataTable()` method to retrieve an ADO.NET `DataTable` object for each list.
3. Add the tables to a `DataSet` object.
4. Create relationships between the tables.
5. Render the data however you like, using `DataList` or `Repeater` or whatever.

Here's some code that shows the broad strokes:

```
protected DataTable GetDataTableFromQuery(string camlQry, SPList theList) {
  SPQuery listQry = new SPQuery();  
  listQry.Query = camlQry;  
  SPListItemCollection listItems = theList.GetItems(listQry);  
  return listItems.GetDataTable();
}

protected void BuildDataSet() {  
  // get SPList objects for the lists in questions ... left as an exercise for the dev -- call them list1, list2, and list3  
  string camlQry = "the CAML necessary to retreive the ites from list1";  
  DataTable table1 = GetDataTable(camlQry, list1);  
  table1.TableName = "Table1";  
  camlQry = "the CAML necessary to retreive the ites from list2";  
  DataTable table2 = GetDataTable(camlQry, list2);  
  table1.TableName = "Table2";  
  camlQry = "the CAML necessary to retreive the ites from list3";  
  DataTable table3 = GetDataTable(camlQry, list3);  
  table1.TableName = "Table3";  

  // now build the DataSet
  DataSet ds = new DataSet();  
  ds.Tables.Add(table1);  
  ds.Tables.Add(table2);  
  ds.Tables.Add(table3);  
  ds.Relations.Add("Table1_2", ds.Tables["Table1"].Columns["FieldA"], ds.Tables["Table2"].Columns["FieldA"]);  
  ds.Relations.Add("Table2_3", ds.Tables["Table2"].Columns["FieldB"], ds.Tables["Table3"].Columns["FieldB"]);  

  // now you can do something with these, like store them in the web part class and bind them to repeaters in the web part's Render() method
}
```